# Is it possible to configure a Hive's UDF?

Tags: hive

I what to access an external resource (database) from a custom Hive's UDF, what is the best way to pass credentials to the UDF?

I tried to set properties via SET:

```
SET my.udf.credentials=...;
SELECT myUdf(someColumn) FROM someTable;
```

and to access them via HiveConf in a GenericUDAFEvaluator's init method, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you're using Hive-0.11.

`GenericUDAFEvaluator` class has the method [configure(MapredContext)](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFEvaluator.html#configure%28org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapredContext%29).
To quote a great man:

> Additionally setup GenericUDAFEvaluator with MapredContext before
>   initializing. This is only called in runtime of MapRedTask.

`MapredContext` class has the method [getJobConf](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/MapredContext.html#getJobConf%28%29).

[`JobConf`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) class has the method [get](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#get%28java.lang.String%29).

Putting it all together:

```
public void configure(MapredContext mapredContext) {
  String credentials = mapredContext.getJobConf().get("my.udf.credentials");
}
```