# How can I access a hive variable within Hive UDF without passing as argument

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to access one/many hive variables, set with `set var=XXX` in my hive UDF [evaluate()](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/UDF.html) function/class.

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23999994/2438951), I can pass these using `${hiveconf:var}`, but can I access these without passing as arguments to the UDF.

I am open to any other means by which I can access a specific set of properties within the UDF that can be passed externally, if above is not possible.